# How to access index of elements of a list within a list

Tags: python

I have a list: `the_board = [['','',''], ['','',''], ['','','']]`.

It will be updated with X's and O's, but I need to make a list which contains a tuple of the indexes that don't have an X or an O.

For example, if the list had an 'X' at index `the_board[1][2]`, the new list should be like: `free_fields = [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2) #note how index [1][2] is not a tuple in the new list.`

How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can doit with simple nested for loops, the first for iterating over the list and the inner loop for iterating over the tuples:

```
for each_tuple in free_fields:
  for each_element in each_tuple:
     #do some work
```

Now if you want a code that generates tuples inside a list  `free_fields`:

```
x = 10 #tuples
free_fields = []
while x <=10:
  free_fields.append(tuple(var_x,var_y))
  x += 1
```

if you want to remove some pair from the list, use `list.remove()` method:

```
free_fields.remove((left_val,right_val))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1
y = 2
free_fields = [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1, 2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)]
the_board = [['','',''], ['','',''], ['','','']]
the_board[x][y] = "X"
print(the_board)
# [['', '', ''], ['', '', 'X'], ['', '', '']]

free_fields.remove((x, y))
print(free_fields)
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Remove it from the list using `.remove()`.

You can put this code in a loop for more values of `x` and `y`.

Note: Do not remove from `free_fields` while iterating on it. Ideally, you should be iterating on values of `x` and `y` and **not** on the `board` and `free_fields`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in python if you need both the index and the item itself you'll use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). In this case you want to have the index to return it, but you also need the content of the rows/cell to inspect the content (check it's empty).

A nice tool you could use to make your code simpler is too use generators ([yield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1720199) form). In this case that will save you the burden of creating a list, adding empty cells indexes and then return it at the end. Instead you'll yield every empty cell indexes.

Putting all these together gives:

```py
def free_fields(board):
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row):
            if not cell:
                yield i, j
            
fields = list(free_fields(the_board))
```

Notice how `free_fields` returns an iterator so we may need to convert it to a list. But if we only need to iterate over empty cells we could simply write:

```py
for i, j in free_fields(the_board):
    print(i, j)
```

Doing this also allows to save the memory we should have used to store the list of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual indexes, iterate by index instead of by item.

```
    free_fields = [ ] 
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range:
            if the_board[i][j] = '' :
                free_fields.append(tuple([i,j])
```